# Storing images on a local site

Tags: images, localhost

sorry for the elementary question.

When I'm building a local site on Wordpress, should I be storing my images in an "img" folder and then using CSS "background-image" to show these photos? That way, when I go live, the image root address won't change.

As it stands, I am just uploading each photos and inserting it directly into the post, then styling it with CSS when need be. However, this means I'm getting big, clunky roots that will have to change when I go live (i.e. localhost/corporate/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/1-new.jpeg).

Comment: Questions related more to CSS and not WordPress specifically should be posted on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: hey Joseph, because the question related to storing images when building on WP, I figured this would be the right forum?

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to managing media. Most common (from my perception) are:

- making live site master copy of data (not doing any data input in local)
- use deployment process that takes care of URL change
- map live domain to local install while working with it
- store media in third location (another server, Amazon S3, etc)